# How to set variables to multiple values (that are integers)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 5 facilities in my division, but the code below in a stored procedure only pulls documents when the "facilityID = 4" unless if I change it manually to represent other ID numbers. So I need the facilityID variable below to point to more than one value like: 
[Set @FacilityID = 1,2,3,4,5] but of course it's not allowing me. If it was characters, I would be able to put them in quotes. Any advice please?

```
declare @facilityID tinyint,
@facilitydivisionID tinyint,

SET @facilityID = 4
SET @facilitydivisionID = 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a table-valued parameter.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Facilities AS TABLE
(
  FacilityID TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then your stored procedure can say:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @FacilityDivisionID TINYINT,
  @Facilities dbo.Facilities READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT ... FROM dbo.wherever AS w
    INNER JOIN @Facilities AS f
    ON f.FacilityID = w.FacilityID
  WHERE w.FacilityDivisionID = @FacilityDivisionID;
END
GO
```

Then you can call it from T-SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @t dbo.Facilities;
INSERT @t VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
DECLARE @d TINYINT = 6;
EXEC dbo.whatever @FacilityDivisionID = @d, @Facilities = @t;
```

Or from C# using a DataTable and a parameter type as Structured. You can search to find plenty of examples of using TVPs from application code.

Comment: Thank you, thats great as I didnt know that I could declare a variable that way by pointing it to a table as a readonly.
Since I have the "Facilities" table already in my database that stores the 5 facilitie's information based on the facilityID, then I have to create the Table Valued Parameter with a different name, correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you will need a different name.

Comment: I keep getting error 137 that the scalar variable needs to be declared, although I declared it as a read only like you showed me above, not sure what am I missing? I will attach the code once I figuer out how to do this here, in my select statement in the stored procedure: I have multipple joins with other tables.
Thanks again.

Comment: I'm looking at the  help for the code block, but I still dont understand how to post my code here, as Indenting four spaces or writing <pre> <code> infront of my code will edit it like the way you have above, please advice, thanks

Comment: @Shayma please don't post code in a comment. If you have further problems getting your new solution to work, please post a new question.